# Ploting custom equation with ggplot2 using column values as parameters

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```r
> data
# A tibble: 146 × 8
   Assignment     `34`     `65`    `231`   `4142`   `7510`        b         a
   <fct>         <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 R5N-H      10610000  8861000  7483000  7886000  7744000  -47163.  8885588.
 2 M6N-H       6263000  4555000  3812000  4663000  -385400 -104969.  4796206.
 3 H7N-H       8146000  6310000  4309000  7618000  3558000  -18879.  6468526.
 4 L11N-H      8366000  7098000  4802000  6127000  7071000  247219.  6518552.
 5 R12N-H     12720000 10660000  8568000  3261000  9081000  -15857.  9396284.
 6 L13N-H     10230000  6487000  4214000 10190000  5159000  -85528.  7008727.
 7 R15N-H     34820000 10150000  4927000  4364000  3138000   -5089. 12022508.
 8 R16N-H     35550000 22340000 13940000 22590000 16240000  -26607. 22953681.
 9 I17N-H     53990000 58300000 42790000  2633000  2464000   -2166. 46652072.
10 A18N-H     77960000 73860000 69700000 63130000 27350000   -8383. 78035247.
# ℹ 136 more rows
```

Columns 2 to 6 are intensity values (arbitrary units) for 5 different times (the column names). Columns "a" and "b" are the parameters of an exponential decay fit (already done) of the form

y = ae^{-bx}

I want to make a plot of intensity vs time for each of the entries in "Assignment" using the 5 different times in columns 2-6. Also, I want to plot the exponential fit using the parameters in columns a and b.

So far I've been able to make the scatter plot by transforming the dataframe to a longer format so I can use faceting and eventually make a single pdf file with all the plots:

```r
data_long <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = !c(Assignment, a,b),
    names_to = "t",
    values_to = "intensity"
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    t = as.numeric(t)
  )

> data_long
# A tibble: 730 × 5
   Assignment        b        a     t intensity
   <fct>         <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 R5N-H       -47163. 8885588.    34  10610000
 2 R5N-H       -47163. 8885588.    65   8861000
 3 R5N-H       -47163. 8885588.   231   7483000
 4 R5N-H       -47163. 8885588.  4142   7886000
 5 R5N-H       -47163. 8885588.  7510   7744000
 6 M6N-H      -104969. 4796206.    34   6263000
 7 M6N-H      -104969. 4796206.    65   4555000
 8 M6N-H      -104969. 4796206.   231   3812000
 9 M6N-H      -104969. 4796206.  4142   4663000
10 M6N-H      -104969. 4796206.  7510   -385400
# ℹ 720 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

```r
plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(
    data = data_long,
    aes(
      x = t,
      y = intensity
    )
  ) +
  facet_wrap_paginate(~Assignment, ncol = 2, nrow = 2,
                      scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

I got covered facet_wrap_paginate part (not shown). The big problem is I don't know how to add the plot of the exponential decay to each subplot in the facet using columns "a" and "b" as parameters. I hope someone can help me out on how to do this.

Comment: You can use a second dataset and `geom_text`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a second dataset and `geom_text`. Here is an example:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ cyl) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"))

dat_text <- data.frame(
  label = c("4 cylinders", "6 cylinders", "8 cylinders"),
  cyl   = c(4, 6, 8),
  cl = c("red", "blue", "black"),
  x     = c(20, 27.5, 25),
  y     = c(4, 4, 4.5)
)

p + geom_text(
  data    = dat_text,
  mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, label = label, colour= cl), show.legend = FALSE
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately, it's not what I need to do. I've already edited my last paragraph because I realized that maybe it was misleading. What I want to do is to plot the exponential model intensity=a exp(-b t) to every subplot using the values in the columns "a" and "b". However, it did come in handy because adding the equation as text is the next step haha. Thank you.